# How can I install pygame on python with cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin

I cannot install pygame on cygwin properly. I tried to follow this old doc    http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/svmsccdoc/node49.html but it doesn't work.

Comment: that page does look a bit complicated, but include much more detail in your question, showing each step that you did and the output, use pastes of the command line, and in particular show what error messages you are getting.  And have you tried installing python and the pygame package natively in windows without cygwin? it may be this isn't a cygwin issue.

Comment: Hi @Barlop, I lost track of everything I did. 2 days full and no results. I just want to quit but I want to teach some students linux and python on linux and that would be the perfect fit , instead of having a VM or a dual boot.

Comment: if you didn't keep notes of your progress/errors and you can't really be bothered to try again then there isn't a lot of point posting the question (unless the unlikely case somebody shows that it's impossible or somebody says here are the steps that work flawlessly for everybody). Maybe the students could VNC to one Linux machine.. Linux can have VNC go to multiple desktops.  I have meddled with pygame a little but on a raspberry pi I don't recall issues installing it, maybe a simple apt-get, not applicable to cygwin.

Comment: also I know nowadays they like to start off by showing people how to make a game, but while it might be exciting, it is a bit overkill, just for students to learn a language. And if students are only interested when it's a game and not interested in the more fundamental(and in a deep sense, actually simpler) aspects then they won't stick through understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that you won't be able to compile `pygame` from source on Cygwin with Cygwin's `gcc-core`. Apparently `src/camera.h` includes `<linux/videodev.h>` (if `__unix__` is defined, which is true for Cygwin), which is not available on Windows, even with Cygwin (you need the Video4Linux framework for that).

I didn't bother to install the Windows binaries, but in principle those should work. Try to explicitly run the system Python from Cygwin rather than the Cygwin Python.

Also, I agree with @barlop: why start with games? There are better things about programming. Even if you insist on writing games, find some better-maintained package that your students can install all by themselves (how can you teach your students when you can't even figure it out yourself?); `pygame` is a crappy package (IMO) that can't even play the standard PyPI game.

Comment: Hi @ksh, what do you mean by `Try to explicitly run the system Python from Cygwin rather than the Cygwin Python.`?

Comment: And what kind of package do you have other than pygame?

Comment: I mean, give the full path of system Python.

Comment: "What kind of package..." I don't know, I don't write and don't care about games. Google is your friend.

Comment: awesome buddy! That does the trick!!! Fu**ing genius you are man!

Answer (score 0):

Why do it within Cygwin? You can execute normal Windows binaries from within the Cygwin environment, so I would opt for installing the native Windows versions of Python and then add PyGame to that. From there you can write/test your code in either Windows or Cygwin, and as Python is a cross-platform language, your code will be the same regardless.

Comment: Hi @BowlesCR, I'm really looking for a way to do it with cygwin. I can go for the easy way e.g python win binaries then pygame binaries on top of it but that's not what I'm looking for. I've tried to install windows python binaries plus the pygame package for windows. I can do an import through the win python gui but not on cygwin. It gives me this >>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame